# Element.addMethods(tagName, ...) has no effect in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Works perfectly when running in PC. But not working when in mobile devices. Anyone knows what is happening?

```
Element.addMethods('INPUT', {
    sayGoodbye: function(element) {
        console.log('Goodbye!');
        return element;
    }
});
$('my-input-textfield').sayGoodbye();
```

Mobile devices says only:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sayGoodbye is not a function
```

p.s. It can be reproduced emulating mobile device in Chrome or Edge.

Comment: I use extended Element methods all the time, and there's never been an issue with mobile. I've never used the type-specific binding... try removing the first argument `'INPUT'` and see if that works.

Comment: which version of PrototypeJS ?

Comment: Yes. Removing 'INPUT' works great. But I was trying to set methods to Input Elements only. And it should work according to prototype.js: [version 1.7](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/addMethods/)